# SilverLight - A way to find which property caused the update to the model

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I've got an MV-VM based SL dialog that seems to fire up a property in the model which I cannot find where it's been triggered from. When debugged the Stack Trace show it as external code. I feel it is the control itself causing a couple of updates for 1 click to the model with wrong data but not extactly sure why since the control (radio button) only gets clicked once. The binding is Twoway.

Thanks
Kodi.

Comment: Please post example code of your view, viewmodel and model. Your description alone isn't enough information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't understand your question well. But, you may try IntelliTrace feature in VS to track it to the point (If you are using VS2010 Ultimate) else you shall try [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/)

HTH